# How to save data to csv file without duplicates in python 3x.?

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 search-item '})
records = []
for result in results:
        name = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'small mb20 colorgreen'})
        city = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'map-item-city block mb0 colorgreen'}).text
        records.append((name, city))
        print (name, city)
        df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ['name', 'city'])
        df.to_csv('gettin.csv', index=False, mode = 'a', encoding='utf-8')
```

In the generated csv file I have two columns (name, city). The first value is duplicated as many times as there are other records.

```
    Name            City
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Wodzireja 55, 59-220 Warszawa
0   1
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Wodzireja 55, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Cholewinka 4, 59-220 Warszawa
0   1
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Wodzireja 55, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Cholewinka 4, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Waclawa 5, 59-220 Warszawa
0   1
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Wodzireja 55, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Cholewinka 4, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Waclawa 5, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Balwanka 5, 59-220 Warszawa
```

How do I get results without duplicates like this?

```
Name                City
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Wodzireja 55, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Cholewinka 4, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Waclawa 5, 59-220 Warszawa
Oddział w Warszawie ul. Balwanka 5, 59-220 Warszawa
```

Comment: How does this work? You have two columns in `df`, but upto 4 values in your "output"? How about you turn this into a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need create `df` outside `loop` and add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
records = []
for result in results:
        name = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'small mb20 colorgreen'})
        city = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'map-item-city block mb0 colorgreen'}).text
        records.append((name, city))
        print (name, city)

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ['name', 'city']).drop_duplicates()
df.to_csv('gettin.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```